# VBA function to copy into new rows depending on the colum values

Tags: excel, vba, unpivot

I`m not a super experienced VBA developer and mostly relly on the Macro recorder, hence would appreciate any help by the community in helping me wrap my head around this problem. I havent used loops in the past but imagine this would be the best application for my problem.

I have the following Table;

| Name | Year | Sec A | Sec B | Sec C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 2020 | 15 | 20 | 30 |
| Mary | 2019 | 5 | 25 | 0 |
| Peter | 2020 | 7 | 0 | 0 |

I would like to copy/paste the name,year and amounts bigger than zero on a new sheet like the following;

| Name | Year | Section | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 2020 | A | 15 |
| Joe | 2020 | B | 20 |
| Joe | 2020 | C | 30 |
| Mary | 2019 | A | 5 |
| Mary | 2019 | B | 25 |
| Peter | 2020 | A | 7 |

The copy/paste operation would continune until it reaches a "0" value on the section columns, then it would continue to the next row, until it reaches the end of the rows.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Skip VBA and use Power Query, using the `Unpivot Columns` functionality.

Comment: many thanks for your reply BigBen, I will be setting up with Power Query as detailed on @JSmart523 comment. Thanks for the supportand your time!

Answer (score 1):

This function will do that. Just create a input table named `ÌnputTable` and an output table named `OutputTable` in your worksheet

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim input_table As Range, output_table As Range
    Set input_table = Range("InputTable")
    Set output_table = Range("OutputTable")
    
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim name As String, year As String, section As String
    
    For i = 1 To input_table.Rows.Count
        name = input_table(i, 1)
        year = input_table(i, 2)
        
        For j = 3 To 5
            section = Chr(62 + j)
            If input_table(i, j).Value > 0 Then
                k = k + 1
                output_table(k, 1) = name
                output_table(k, 2) = year
                output_table(k, 3) = section
                output_table(k, 4) = input_table(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks @danneedebro, I will be testing your solution. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

@BigBen's comment is right.

In Excel, highlight your source table, choose Insert Table (or press ctrl-t) making sure you check that your table has a header row.

Then, in the table ribbon (when your cursor is in the table) rename your table to "Source"

Then, in the Data ribbon, in the "Get & Transform" section, click "From Table". This will create a query that pulls from this table, and present it for editing in the Power Query Editor.

In the Home ribbon of the Power Query editor, click Manage - Reference. This will create a new query that uses/starts with the current one. I recommend renaming it (in the right sidebar).

In the home ribbon of the Power Query editor, click Advanced Editor and paste the following:

```
let
    Source = Source,
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"Sec A", "A"}, {"Sec B", "B"}, {"Sec C", "C"}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Renamed Columns", {"Name", "Year"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Columns", each [Value] <> 0)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

You'll now have what you want.

Don't be scared of that code, by the way. I didn't really type all that! After creating the second query,

- I double-clicked the column headers to rename them.
- I highlighted the last three columns and clicked "Unpivot Columns" from the Transform ribbon.
- I clicked the filter for the "Value" column to only get rows where Value wasn't 0.

and that was it!

Comment: Thanks @JSmart523, I have tested this solution and it works flawlessly. Once I  set up the Power Query, per your instructions eill just need tyo add an automatic refresh everytime the source data is modified. Thanks for the support and the detailed walktrough!

Answer (score 1):

### Custom UnPivot RCV by Rows

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub UnPivotRCVbyRowsCustom()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1" ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1" ' Source First Cell Range
    Const rlCount As Long = 2 ' Row Labels (repeating columns) Count
    Const vException As Variant = 0 ' Value Exception
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet2" ' Destination Worksheet Name
    Const dstFirst As String = "A1" ' Destination First Cell Range
    Const HeaderList As String = "Name,Year,Section,Total"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = defineEndRange(ws.Range(srcFirst).CurrentRegion, srcFirst)
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rng.Value
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(Data, 1) ' Source Rows Count
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = UBound(Data, 2) ' Source Columns Count
    
    ' Calculate Exceptions Count.
    Set rng = rng.Resize(srCount - 1, scCount - rlCount) _
        .Offset(1, rlCount)
    Dim eCount As Long: eCount = Application.CountIf(rng, vException)
    
    ' Rename column labels in Data Array.
    Dim fvCol As Long: fvCol = 1 + rlCount ' First Value Column
    Dim j As Long ' Source Columns Counter
    For j = fvCol To scCount
        Data(1, j) = Right(Data(1, j), 1)
    Next j
    
    ' Define Result Array.
    Dim drCount As Long ' Destination Rows Count
    drCount = (srCount - 1) * (scCount - rlCount) - eCount + 1
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = rlCount + 2 ' Destination Columns Count
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    ' Write headers to Result Array.
    Dim Headers() As String: Headers = Split(HeaderList, ",")
    For j = 1 To dcCount
        Result(1, j) = Headers(j - 1)
    Next j
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Result Array.
    Dim i As Long ' Source Rows Counter
    Dim k As Long: k = 1 ' Destination Rows Counter
    Dim l As Long ' Destination Columns Counter
    For i = 2 To srCount
        For j = fvCol To scCount
            If Data(i, j) <> vException Then
                k = k + 1
                For l = 1 To rlCount
                    Result(k, l) = Data(i, l)
                Next l
                Result(k, l) = Data(1, j)
                Result(k, l + 1) = Data(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst).Resize(, dcCount)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(drCount).Value = Result
    End With

End Sub

Function defineEndRange( _
    rng As Range, _
    ByVal FirstCellAddress As String) _
As Range
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        With rng.Areas(1)
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim cel As Range: Set cel = .Worksheet.Range(FirstCellAddress)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                If Not Intersect(rng.Areas(1), cel) Is Nothing Then
                    Set defineEndRange = cel.Resize( _
                       .Rows.Count + .Row - cel.Row, _
                       .Columns.Count + .Column - cel.Column)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thank you @VBasic 2008. I will be testing your code as well, really appreciate the support and your time!

Answer (score 1):

I am new to VBA as well, so I am taking this as a practice. Here is the code I wrote. May not be the best solution but it does work.

```
Sub copyandpastedata()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim char As String


'Define last position where a data exist
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


'Delete all worksheets other than sheet1(where the raw data is)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Create a new sheet and name it to NewData
Sheets.Add(after:=Sheet1).Name = "NewData"
With Sheets("NewData")
    .Range("A1") = "Name"
    .Range("B1") = "Year"
    .Range("C1") = "Section"
    .Range("D1") = "Total"
End With


'Loop through raw data and find matches
i = 2
With Sheet1
    For Each cell In .Range("C2", .Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
        If VBA.IsNumeric(cell) Then
            If cell > 0 Then
                .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Copy Sheets("NewData").Cells(i, 1)           'Copy Name to the new sheet
                .Cells(cell.Row, 2).Copy Sheets("NewData").Cells(i, 2)           'Copy Year to the new sheet
                char = Right(.Cells(1, cell.Column), 1)                          'Look for section letter ID
                Sheets("NewData").Cells(i, 3) = char                             'Copy section to the new sheet
                .Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Copy Sheets("NewData").Cells(i, 4) 'Copy Total to the new sheet
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With



End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @cc585, good to know a fellow student of VBA. I will be testing your solution, many thanks for the assitance and your time!